# Online resources for networking and creating new mathematical collaborations

Tags: soft-question, online-resources, research, career-development

Are there any online resources (**forums**, **social networking websites**, etc.) that focus on **bringing together mathematicians** that seek to

> **extend their range of collaborations and ongoing work** beyond their usual avenues;

*or*

> **contribute to** projects in **other sciences** (biology, chemistry, medicine, archaeology) that may require some specialized knowledge that is out of the range of "mathematical biologist", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [the PolyMath wiki](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Main_Page) might be one place to start?